# Numeric(15,6) - The decimal field's precision is too small

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2005, decimal, ms-access-2003

I add a decimal field in ms access 2003. Its data type is **Numeric(15,6)**.

In access, I define it like below

> Data Type: 'Numeric'.
>
> Field Size : Decimal
>
> Precision : 15
>
> Scale : 6
>
> Decimal Places : 6

From Window application, I try to modify its value to

> '123456.22223'

. I got this error -

> The decimal field's precision is too small to accept the numeric you attempted to add.

But in ms access, using sql command, I can update this value. Why?

My vb.net code is below

```
mClass.ExchRate = IIf(txtExchRate.Text = "", 0.0, CDec(txtExchRate.Text))
```

Here, data type of ExchRate field of mClass is also decimal. And then pass this value to sql update command.

Comment: What code are you using to update with your windows application?

Comment: @Random832, please see my question below.

Comment: For precision 15 and scale 6, I think you'll need Numeric (15,6). See [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190476.aspx) for a general definitions for scale and precision. For `'123456.22223`, you'll atleast need `Numeric(11,5)`

Comment: @Bala R, in ms access, I define it Numeric(15,6). So it covers, i think. because i can update by sql command in ms access. Now this error happened in window application.

Comment: I can save 6 decimal points like this '23.123456' but can't save this '12345.123456'. Is there any limitation in decimal type in ms access?

Comment: What data type are you using in your code?  As a double, the number 123456.22223 in memory is actually 123546.222229999999399296939373016357421875
.  Could that be causing the problem?  Can you use a decimal data type instead of double?

Comment: @Chris Dunaway, I use decimal in both sites - window application and ms access.

Comment: @Chris Dunaway, I test it with double in my code. It works.